# Using captcha on Orbeon form

Tags: orbeon

Here is the form I created on the Orbeon website:

http://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/0860411ecf1bff6128bd802784ee22a33b0bab68

I can display captcha but seems it's not validated when I run the form and move to the next page (this is a multi-page form). Anything else that I missed?

Here is the captcha code, added by editing source code of form builder

```
<fr:simple-captcha id="my-captcha">
  <xf:send ev:event="fr-verify-done" submission="save-submission"/>
  <xf:action ev:event="fr-verify-error">
      <xf:toggle case="failure-case"/>
      <xf:dispatch target="my-captcha" name="fr-reload"/>
  </xf:action>
</fr:simple-captcha>`
```

Comment: If you'd like to have a captcha on your form, have you tried setting the [`oxf.fr.detail.captcha.*.*` property](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner/detail-page#captcha)? The captcha components are expected to be used through this property, instead of being manually added to the form.

Comment: Yes Erik, but this is a multi page form, and what I want is the captcha to be displayed on the first page (or first section in orbeon term).

Comment: If you enable the captcha, it will always show at the bottom of the form, and users will need to fill it out before they can do an operation like saving or submitting. Then can do it right away, or later on, but again will have to do it before they save or submit the data. This isn't enough in your scenario?

Comment: Chris, did you get a chance to try the `oxf.fr.detail.captcha.*.*` property to enable the captcha? If so, is this doing what you're looking for?